# terminate current class and going to another class . both are in a package

Tags: java

for example Class_One = current class and Class_Two = another class .

i used this code

```
Class_Two.main(args);
```

but i want to exit from Class_One after going to Class_Two.
thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear, to me, at least. Can you share some more context - e.g., your entire code block?

Comment: What do you mean by "terminate"? Are you just looking for `return`?

Comment: i want to exit class_one and start class_two.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "exit" a class, i suppose you mean you want to terminate the method `main()` you are calling.

This really depends on what and how you want to achieve;

if you want to run in parallel a method from class one and two, the you should use thread;

if after some time the class one method is running you want to stop it and run class two methods you should somehow make the method stop itself after a while, or run the method in a separate thread and from the father thread set a flag to tell the child it should stop (java has no way to kill a child thread, as it use a cooperative thread model );

if the child thread somehow break and may start infinite loop, and you have no way to access the code and fix it, you could run it in a separate process, then you have control to kill the child process, BUT you loose all the variable sharing and you have to find a way to make the two process talk; there are many way and you are entering the vast land of `Inter-process communication`

Comment: in my program i used RMI. that server waits and using the port. i need this port in other class.. :)

Comment: then you have two main solution:
both of them have to share the RMI object to make the call, as the port can be used only one time, but the RMI object support multiple parallel call.

So solution n°1 is to use asincronous call, and solution n°2 is to run the two class in two different thread.

Comment: how can i release port after send or recive?

Comment: closing the Server object. But normally you don't want to do that, but share it between all your classes that need it.

Comment: thanks .. :) i used another port for other class :))